# How can I know the past questions I viewed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I found a very useful question on Stack Overflow. I forgot to bookmark the page or mark the question as favourite. After some 10days, I faced the same problem and I know that answer (the answer to that question I viewed 10days ago) is the perfect solution to my problem. I searched the question again, but it was really hard to find it out. It was nearly impossible to find that question by searching. Since I viewed that question as a user who has logged in, I hope that there might be my browsing history stored somewhere on Stack Overflow.

Is it possible to know the questions I viewed in the past?

Comment: Oh no. I am checking the firefox history. If I can't find it then I want to Ask these type of questions in metastackoverflow Right?.

Comment: Yap...
[Another X characters...]

Comment: ys thanks infinity. I found it on Firefox history.:-)

Comment: now I marked it as favourite question.

Comment: Ach, beat me by 20 seconds @Sha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to know the questions I viewed in the past?

No. If you have only viewed the question and you don't know it's link, the only possible option is [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

However if you have voted on that post then you can view all posts you have voted for from the *votes* tab from your profile. Or if you have commented on that post then you can see that from [activity->comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2351696/suhail?tab=activity&sort=comments) tab from your profile.

So if you want to see the answer in future then make the question as a favorite. Then you can find id from [your favorite tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2351696/suhail?tab=favorites). Or you can search withing [your favorite questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites:mine).